# Eclipse: Restore the error colors to the default

Tags: eclipse

I have changed the configuration of my Eclipse and now it works weird when I have a syntax error in my code. it looks like the below code:

[image]

so the code inside the highlighted part is not readable.

So, how can i change the configuration of eclipse to default for error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This should help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc6fU.png)

Right click on the text editor>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors>Annotations

Select "Errors" and change the "Text as" property to "Native Problem Underline"